# QMessageBox, dialog for Yes/No shows a run time error

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault

I have a snippet of the form

```
    path = <Defined here>
    QMessageBox::StandardButton result = QMessageBox::No
    if (condition that is true) {
        result = QMessageBox::question(mainWindow(),"Title" ,i18n( "A path, "
            "%1, is set in System Settings.\nWould you like to use that?"
          , path ),QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No,QMessageBox::Yes);
    }
```

But I get a SIGSEGV error everytime. I tried debugging with Qt Creator and this is the last call, after which the control goes to the libraries. I don't need anybody solving the bug. Just pointing out what all could have gone wrong. In case you need the backtrace.

[Backtrace](http://pastebin.com/nr0E8TVD)

Comment: Could it be that `i18n` call returns `nullptr`?

Comment: I thought of it earlier. Completely removed i18n and changed with some string like "FooBar". Still I get the SIGSEGV